# Synchronizing zoom states between two ECharts in React leads to zoom "snap back"

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, echarts

I'm working with ECharts in a React application, and I've encountered an issue when synchronizing the zoom state between two line charts. The desired behavior is that when one chart's zoom is changed, the other should reflect the same zoom level. However, I've found that upon adjusting the zoom on one chart, it seems to "snap back" to its original position.

Here's a simplified representation of the code:

```js
// LineChart.tsx

export const LineChart = React.forwardRef<ReactECharts, LineChartProps>((props, ref) => {
  { zoomState, onDataZoom } = props

  const option: EChartsOption = {
    dataZoom: [{
      type: 'slider',
      start: zoomState.start,
      end: zoomState.end,
    }],
  }

  return (
    <ReactECharts 
      ref={ref} 
      option={option}
      onEvents={{
        'datazoom': onDataZoom,
      }}
    />
  );
});

// index.tsx

const [zoomState, setZoomState] = useState<{start: number, end: number}>({ start: 80, end: 100 });

function onDataZoom(params: any) {
    const newZoom = { start: params.start, end: params.end };
    setZoomState(newZoom);
}

var co2Chart = (
    <LineChart 
      ref={co2ChartRef}
      data={device.deviceData}
      zoomState={zoomState}
      onDataZoom={onDataZoom}
      valueToPlot={'co2'}
      // ... (rest of the props)
    />
)

var tempChart = (
    <LineChart 
      ref={tempChartRef}
      data={device.deviceData}
      zoomState={zoomState}
      onDataZoom={onDataZoom}
      valueToPlot={'temperature'}
      // ... (rest of the props)
    />
)
```

From my observations:

- Upon initiating a zoom change (by dragging the zoom slider on one chart), the datazoom event fires.
- The onDataZoom function attempts to set the new zoom state.
- Before React updates the state and re-renders the component, the LineChart component seems to re-render due to ECharts' internal behaviors.
- As the state hasn't been updated yet, the chart reverts to the old zoom state, triggering another datazoom event.
- This seems to create a feedback loop, causing the "snap back" effect.

I am still learning React and although I think I understand what's happening, I'm not sure how to resolve it.

Comment: There are built in mechanisms to synchronize zoom on different charts. See [this example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=scatter-anscombe-quartet&edit=1&reset=1) and add `dataZoom: [{ type: 'slider', xAxisIndex: 'all' }]` to option. [`xAxisIndex`](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#dataZoom-slider.xAxisIndex) specifies the synchronized xAxes.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve the zoom "snap back" issue by implementing a debouncing technique for the onDataZoom function. This strategy effectively breaks the feedback loop between React's asynchronous state updates and ECharts' own rendering cycle.

**Why Debouncing Works**

When you drag the zoom slider in ECharts, the datazoom event fires multiple times in rapid succession. Each of these events would normally trigger a React state update, leading to unwanted behavior due to the feedback loop between ECharts and React. Debouncing the onDataZoom function limits the rate at which it can be invoked, essentially waiting for a set amount of time to pass without any new invocations before actually running the original function. This gives React enough time to update its state and re-render the component, effectively synchronizing the zoom state between the two charts.

```js
// index.tsx
import { debounce } from 'lodash';

function onDataZoom(params: any) {
  const newZoom = { start: params.start, end: params.end };
  setZoomState(newZoom);
}

const debouncedOnDataZoom = debounce(onDataZoom, 200);

var co2Chart = (
  <LineChart 
    data={device.deviceData}
    zoomState={zoomState}
    onDataZoom={debouncedOnDataZoom}
    valueToPlot={'co2'}
  >
)
```